# Why does my multilayer perceptron's output converge to 0.5?

Tags: javascript, xor, perceptron

I'm currently developing a neural network to solve XOR issue with Javascript. I have 2 inputs, 2 hidden neurons and 1 output. I added 1 bias in each layer. My output keeps converging to 0.5 despite the fact that I decreased my learning rate and checked the values of my weights to ensure that they got initialized randomly.

I don't know what I should do... please help me.

```js
class Matrix {

    /*  Paramètres : 
        Table : tableau bidimensionnel */ 
    constructor (table) {
        this.table = table;
        this.h = table.length; 
        this.w = table[0].length; 
    }

    getTable () {
        return this.table; 
    }

    dot (arr, bias = []) {

        let m = []; 

        for (let i = 0; i < this.h; i++) {
            let s = 0; 
            for (let j = 0; j < this.w; j++) {
                s += this.table[i][j] * arr[i]; 
            }
            if (bias.length > 0) {
                s += bias[i]; 
            }
            m.push([s]); 
        }
    
        return new Matrix(m).getTable(); 

    }

    
}

class Brain { // Les poids peuvent être initialisés à 0 !!!

    constructor (inputs, hiddens, outputs) {
        //this.inputs = Array.from(Array(inputs), n => Math.round(Math.random())); // Entrées binaires (0 ou 1)
        this.inputs = Array(); 

        this.weights_l1 = Array.from(Array(hiddens), x => (Array.from(Array(inputs), n => Math.random() * 5))) // Initialisation des poids de la première couche
        this.weights_l2 = Array.from(Array(outputs), x => (Array.from(Array(hiddens), n => Math.random() * 5))) // Initialisation des poids de la deuxième couche

        this.weights_l1_gradient = Array.from(Array(hiddens), x => (Array.from(Array(inputs), n => 0)))
        this.weights_l2_gradient = Array.from(Array(outputs), x => (Array.from(Array(hiddens), n => 0)))

        this.bias_l1 = [Math.random() * 5, Math.random() * 5]; 
        this.bias_l2 = Math.random() * 5; 

        this.bias_l1_gradient = [0, 0];  
        this.bias_l2_gradient = [0]; 

        this.nb_inputs = inputs; 
        this.nb_hiddens = hiddens; 
        this.nb_outputs = outputs; 

        this.learning_rate = 0.2; 
    }

    set (dataset) {
        this.dataset = dataset; 
    }

    sigmoid (x) {
        return (1 / (1 + Math.exp(-x))); 
    }

    sigmoid_der (x) {
        return x * (1 - x); 
    }

    getOutputs (values) {
        let outputs = Array();

        for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            outputs.push(this.sigmoid(values[i])); 
        }

        return outputs; 
    }

    initGradients () {
        this.weights_l1_gradient = Array.from(Array(this.nb_hiddens), x => (Array.from(Array(this.nb_inputs), n => 0)))
        this.weights_l2_gradient = Array.from(Array(this.nb_outputs), x => (Array.from(Array(this.nb_hiddens), n => 0)))
        this.bias_l1_gradient = [0, 0]; 
        this.bias_l2_gradient = 0; 
    }

    think () {
        
        let values_l1 = new Matrix(this.weights_l1);

        let arr = values_l1.dot(this.inputs, this.bias_l1); 

        this.outputs_l1 = this.getOutputs(arr); 
        
        let values_l2 = new Matrix(this.weights_l2); 

        let arr2 = values_l2.dot(this.outputs_l1, this.bias_l2); 

        this.output = this.getOutputs(arr2)[0]; 

        console.log(this.output); 
    }

    learn () {

        this.initGradients(); 

        // On parcourt le dataset
        for (let i = 0; i < this.dataset.length; i++) {

            this.inputs[0] = this.dataset[i][0]; 
            this.inputs[1] = this.dataset[i][1]; 
            this.target = this.dataset[i][2]; 

            this.think(); // On parcourt le réseau 
            
            this.error = this.output - this.target; 
            console.log("error: " + this.error); 
            console.log("output: " + this.output); 

            for (let i = 0; i < this.weights_l1_gradient.length; i++) {
                for (let j = 0; j < this.weights_l1_gradient[i].length; j++) {
                    this.weights_l1_gradient[i][j] += this.error * this.sigmoid_der(this.outputs_l1[i]) * this.inputs[i]; 
                }
            }

            for (let i = 0; i < this.bias_l1_gradient.length; i++) {
                this.bias_l1_gradient[i] += this.error * this.sigmoid_der(this.outputs_l1[i]); 
            }

            for (let i = 0; i < this.weights_l2_gradient.length; i++) {
                for (let j = 0; j < this.weights_l2_gradient[i].length; j++) {
                    this.weights_l2_gradient[i][j] += this.error * this.sigmoid_der(this.output) * this.outputs_l1[i]; 
                }
            }

            this.bias_l2_gradient += this.error * this.sigmoid_der(this.output); 
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < this.weights_l1.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < this.weights_l1[i].length; j++) {
                this.weights_l1[i][j] -= this.weights_l1_gradient[i][j] * this.learning_rate; 
            }
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < this.bias_l1.length; i++) {
            this.bias_l1[i] -= this.bias_l1_gradient[i] * this.learning_rate; 
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < this.weights_l2.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < this.weights_l2[i].length; j++) {
                this.weights_l2[i][j] -= this.weights_l2_gradient[i][j] * this.learning_rate; 
            }
        }

        this.bias_l2 -= this.bias_l2_gradient * this.learning_rate;  

    }
}

let brain = new Brain(2, 2, 1); 

let dataset = [
    [1, 1, 0], 
    [1, 0, 1], 
    [0, 1, 1], 
    [0, 0, 0]
]; 

brain.set(dataset); 

for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    brain.learn(); 
}
```

Thank you.